# Matlab: Create a KML file which contains multiple lines of coordinates

Tags: xml, matlab, coordinates, kml, google-earth

I am trying to plot airplane flight trajectories on GoogleEarth using Matlab to build the KML file. I am very new to Matlab. My code thus far has been successful in using XML nodes to format the correct KML file but I am having difficulty getting the many lines of coordinates from a csv or xls file to the KML file. I can only ever get one coordinate to be written to the file or all of the coordinates horizontally which is not correctly formatted.

I have been able to copy and paste the coordinates into the written KML file after the script has run its course, but I need to be able to tell the script to do that.

The current code is not robust, I do not yet know how to catch exceptions and prevent the code from failing in Matlab. I also realize that my use of the for loop to create the char array which holds my coordinates is very inefficient. If anyone knows of a way to make this more efficient that would also help.

```
trajectoryData = struct('Longitude',[],'Latitude',[],'Altitude',[]);
data = xlsread('Table.xls');
[m,n]=size(data);
trajectoryData.Longitude = data(:,1);
trajectoryData.Latitude = data(:,2);
trajectoryData.Altitude = data(:,3);

xDoc = com.mathworks.xml.XMLUtils.createDocument('kml');
xDocRootNode = xDoc.getDocumentElement;
documentNode = xDoc.createElement('Document');
nameNode = xDoc.createElement('name');
styleNode = xDoc.createElement('Style');
lineStyleNode = xDoc.createElement('LineStyle');
polyStyleNode = xDoc.createElement('PolyStyle');
colorNode = xDoc.createElement('color');
widthNode = xDoc.createElement('width');
placemarkNode = xDoc.createElement('Placemark');
visibilityNode = xDoc.createElement('visibility');
styleUrlNode = xDoc.createElement('styleUrl');
altitudeNode = xDoc.createElement('altitudeMode');
coordinatesNode = xDoc.createElement('coordinates');
lineStringNode = xDoc.createElement('LineString');
extrudeNode = xDoc.createElement('extrude');
tessellateNode = xDoc.createElement('tessellate');

nameNode.setTextContent('FlightID 26');
colorNode.setTextContent('7f00ff00');
widthNode.setTextContent('4');
visibilityNode.setTextContent('1');
styleUrlNode.setTextContent('#yellowLineGreenPoly');
extrudeNode.setTextContent('1');
tessellateNode.setTextContent('1');
altitudeNode.setTextContent('absolute');

xDocRootNode.appendChild(documentNode);
documentNode.appendChild(nameNode);
documentNode.appendChild(styleNode);
documentNode.appendChild(placemarkNode);
styleNode.appendChild(lineStyleNode);
styleNode.appendChild(polyStyleNode);
polyStyleNode.appendChild(colorNode);
lineStyleNode.appendChild(colorNode);
lineStyleNode.appendChild(widthNode);
lineStringNode.appendChild(altitudeNode);
lineStringNode.appendChild(extrudeNode);
lineStringNode.appendChild(tessellateNode);
lineStringNode.appendChild(coordinatesNode);
placemarkNode.appendChild(visibilityNode);
placemarkNode.appendChild(styleUrlNode);
placemarkNode.appendChild(lineStringNode);



for i=1:numel(data(1:end,1))
     coord = char(coord,strcat(num2str(trajectoryData.Longitude(i,1)),',',...
        num2str(trajectoryData.Latitude(i,1)),',',num2str(trajectoryData.Altitude(i,1))))
     for j=1:27
        coordinateNode = xDoc.createTextNode(coord(i,j));
        coordinatesNode.appendChild(coordinateNode);
     end


end

xDocRootNode.appendChild(documentNode);

xmlwrite('KMLFile2.kml',xDoc);
```

This is the output of the script as it is:

```
<coordinates> latitude,longitude,altitude latitude,longitude,altitude </coordinates>
```

I just need a way to format the kml like this:

```
<coordinates>
    latitude,longitude,altitude
    latitude,longitude,altitude
</coordinates>
```

Comment: What are the difficulties you're having? How is the above code failing? It's not clear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

From a pure KML perspective, there isn't a problem with writing your coordinates horizontally, as long as they are separated by at least 1 space.

However, if you'd like to change the formatting, I believe you could simply add a newline `\n` character to the area where you are constructing your KML coordinate strings.

It would look instead like this:

```
    coord = char(coord,strcat( ...
                  num2str(trajectoryData.Longitude(i,1)), ',' ,...
                  num2str(trajectoryData.Latitude(i,1)) , ',' ,...
                  num2str(trajectoryData.Altitude(i,1)) , ' \n'));
```

This should inject newline characters into your KML, creating the formatting that you desire.